# Generating uniformly distributed random elements of $SU(3)$

Tags: probability, lie-groups, haar-measure

Say I need to generate a uniformly distributed collection $\{X\}$ of elements of $SU(3)$.  (For concreteness, I will consider the distribution to be uniform if the distribution of  $X$ is identical to the distribution of $gX$ where $g$ can be any element of $SU(3)$.)

I know how to generate uniform random elements of $SU(2)$ because it is isomorphic with $SO(3)$ and I know how to generate random rotations.  In past work, I (and other Lattice Gauge Theory people doing Monte-Carlo simulations) needed to generate random $SU(3)$ elements such that the probability of an element is the same as that of its inverse, and such that the probability density near at $SU(3)$ element is non-zero.   However, these are weaker conditions than uniformity, and what we did was to take the product of three elements in three different $SU(2)$ subspaces of $SU(3)$.  We could get arbitrarily close to a uniform distribution by multiplying several such products.

But I would like to know how to generate $SU(3)$ elements with uniform distribution, not just almost-uniform distribution.

Comment: $SU(2)$ is indeed not isomorphic to $SO(3)$. And can you add more tags (probability?)?

Comment: I barely know about this subject, but it seems to me that a quick googling shows some references that might interest you, like [*this*](http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20[paper].pdf).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Random%20unitary%20[paper].pdf . Incidentally, the uniform distribution here is called Haar measure if you want another keyword to use.

Comment: Probably, using this post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69352/topology-of-su3 and using normal distributions to generate uniform distribution on spheres will work?

Comment: This MathOverflow question looks relevant (though not definitive, since it's about SO(n) rather than SU(n)): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78029/how-to-correctly-generate-uniformly-distibuted-random-elements-from-son